# Imageview over another imageview

Tags: android

[image]

I want to arrange two imageviews as shown in the pic programatically. One is the profile photo and one is white pencil in blue circle.

This is how I had set width and height of the main profile pic

```
int px = metrics.heightPixels / 4;
profilePic = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.profilePic);
profilePic.getLayoutParams().width = px;
profilePic.getLayoutParams().height = px;
```

If I do it in xml, it will create problems in different screen sizes.
How to achieve this programatically?

Answer (score 1):

Put two imageview inside the relativelayout. Make the images circular and align the small imageview in relativelayout with bottom|left layout gravity.

Answer (score 0):

try following,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="-20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here the main thing is to give float margin like -20 is important.